# Datagridview Scroll Event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to know how to use the scroll event handler in `Datagridview`. I have a very big table of around 20 columns. It would fit in the screen.

So, when I scroll in the horizontal direction, when a particular column go out of focus, I need to call some function.

Any idea, how to achieve it ?

Something similar :

```
 private void datagridview_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            //If namecol go out of focus
             //foo();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did :

```
 private void datagridview_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
            {

                if (e.NewValue > this.check1.Width/2 )
                   foo();
                else
                   hoo();
            }
        }
```

Thanks